# Displaying data with button-click by combining 3 mysql tables

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

I have a problem of displaying database-table in a table format, something like the following:

[image]

Before I present you with the code that I used I would like to describe the situation (keep in mind that I am not advanced in programming plus I worked on a sample code that I found out there... somewhere).

I have 3 different tables. They are as follows:

**Table 1:** id| country | id_value

**Table 2:** id | country | id_value | breed

**Table 3:** id | owner | contact | id_value

As you can observe I am using the id_value parameter to connect them.

After I managed to connect dropdown-menu1 to table 1, I can select an option and that automatically filters table 2, which allows me to chose something from the (filtered) dropdown menu 2.

**The problem:** 
Below of it I have a button, that is supposed to do the following:
After the choices are made by the visitor/user, and tables 1/2 have been filtered, to click on the button and inside a div, or something, *to display the corresponding results from table 3*.

Now here are the codes:

**The main_php:**
(the following code was used inside the head -tags)

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function AjaxFunction()
    {
   var httpxml;
    try
     {
      // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
     httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     catch (e)
    {
    // Internet Explorer
      try
                {
             httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
        catch (e)
                {
            try
        {
        httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }
            catch (e)
        {
        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
        return false;
        }
        }
   }
 function stateck() 
 {
  if(httpxml.readyState==4)
  {
 //alert(httpxml.responseText);
 var myarray = JSON.parse(httpxml.responseText);
 // Remove the options from 2nd dropdown list 
  for(j=document.testform.subcat.options.length-1;j>=0;j--)
 {
 document.testform.subcat.remove(j);
 }


    for (i=0;i<myarray.data.length;i++)
   {
  var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
  optn.text = myarray.data[i].breed;
   optn.value = myarray.data[i].id_values;  // You can change this to subcategory 
    document.testform.subcat.options.add(optn);

  } 
  }
 } // end of function stateck
 var url="connect_data/dd.php";
 var cat_id=document.getElementById('s1').value;
 url=url+"?cat_id="+cat_id;
 url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
 httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateck;
 //alert(url);
 httpxml.open("GET",url,true);
 httpxml.send(null);
   }
</script>
```

in the body:

```
    <form name="testform" method='POST' action='mainck.php'>
    Name:<input type=text name=fname>
    <?Php
    require "connect_data/config.php";// connection to database 

     echo "<br>Select Category first  <select name=cat id='s1'        onchange=AjaxFunction();>
     <option value=''>Select One</option>";

      $sql="select DISTINCT id_values, country from the_countries ORDER BY country"; // Query to collect data from table 

    foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo "<option value=$row[id_values]>$row[country]</option>";
    }
    ?>
   </select>
   <br>
   Select Subcategory 
       <select name=subcat id='s2'>

   </select><br><input type=submit value=submit>
   </form>
```

**the dd.php that was used** (<-this php basically gets the data from the first dropdown menu, connects it to the second and back the code goes to the main.php to populate the second dropdown menu from the filtered data of table 2).

```
   <?Php
   @$cat_id=$_GET['cat_id'];
  //$cat_id=2;
 /// Preventing injection attack //// 
  if(!is_numeric($cat_id)){
 echo "Data Error";
  exit;
    }
   /// end of checking injection attack ////
  require "config.php";

  $sql="select DISTINCT breed,id_values from breeds_list where id_values='$cat_id' ORDER BY breed";
  $row=$dbo->prepare($sql);
  $row->execute();
  $result=$row->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  $main = array('data'=>$result);
  echo json_encode($main);
  ?>
```

Finally, after all that is done, according to the sample code everything is supposed to go to a file called
**mainck.php** and is the following one (<- **please note:** this part I did not touch at all because this is the point where I hit a wall and I don't know how to proceed).

```
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 3.2//en">



  <body >

   <?Php

  echo "\$_POST['fname'] = $_POST[fname]<br>
   \$_POST['cat'] = $_POST[cat]<br>
  \$_POST['subcat'] = $_POST[subcat]
  ";

    /*
  while (list ($key,$val) = each ($_POST)) {
 echo "\$$key = $val";
 echo "<br>";
 } 
  */
  ?>

 <br><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);">

 </body>
```

To conclude, all I want is to click that bloody-button and get the corresponding data (after table 1 and table 2 have been filtered) from Table 3.

Comment: You might want to consider trimming this down by about 90%. This is not a [mcve]

Comment: Hi Miken32: what do you mean by trimming it down. I was asked by another member here to post everything that I have done so as for you guys to (propably) be able to help me out. So, following his suggestion I posted everything I did so far. If, on the other hand, by trimming you mean that the code is weird etc. truth be told, its the only code sample that I found, that I was able to understand and to adjust it to my case. So I am going for what I have so far...